# Вопрос по ssl сертификату для поддомена

Tags: ssl, поддомены

Поддомен припаркован к одному хостингу, основной домен к другому.
Перенести всё на 1 хостинг нельзя. Основной домен припаркован к конструктору лендингов.

Хостинг поддомена не может выдать сертификат т.к. у основного домена А-запись ведёт на другой хостинг. Это технический нюанс. Типа сертификат распространяется с основного на поддомены.

В прошлый раз для выдачи сертификата, меняли а запись обратно на хостинг поддомена и сайт не работал. СЕйчас сертификат истёк, и опять получается нужно опять её менять.

Как сделать, чтобы сертификат на поддомене продлевался автоматом без смен А-записей?